# How does hidden_field_tag works in an reset password form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, hidden-field

It's being really hard to understand how a form work with hidden_field_tag in a specific situation. I wish someone would explain me what happens.

It's the form from reset password from [railstutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/password_reset#code-password_reset_form).

My view is:

```
<% provide(:title, 'Reset password') %>
<h1>Reset password</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <%= form_for(@user, url: password_reset_path(params[:id])) do |f| %>
      <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

      <%= hidden_field_tag :email, @user.email %>

      <%= f.label :password %>
      <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation" %>
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.submit "Update password", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

My update action and the strong params method:

```
  def update
    if params[:user][:password].empty?
      @user.errors.add(:password, "can't be empty")
      render 'edit'
    elsif @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      log_in @user
      @user.update_attribute(:reset_digest, nil)
      flash[:success] = "Password has been reset."
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:password, :password_confirmation)
  end
```

When access the edit action, the user enter an email an the app send a link to this email, with an activation token, like this path:

```
/password_resets/9Ij91DFChTeWTitNDVJfYw/edit?email=example%40railstutorial.org
```

The user open this link and change the password. That is perfectly functional. My question is: if I already have the user from the edit action and doesn't use `params[:email]` (provided with the hidden_field_tag) explicitly in my update action, why do I need the hidden tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actions are separate from each other. When you first render your password reset form in scope of the `edit` action, your `@user` instance variable, being somehow initialized before, is used to supply a value for the hidden email field.

When later user submits the form, its data gets processed by the `update` action in a completely separate request. This request does not know what happened before, specifically, that the form was originally rendered by the `edit` action. It also doesn't have access to any of the objects that were there in scope of the `edit` action.

In order to process the request, your `update` action code needs to initialize all the objects it needs anew, and that is primarily the `@user` object.

If current action doesn't know what happened before, how it would know which user record should go to the `@user` variable? It can find the user by email, this is why you supplied it in the params. Your `edit` action code made it available for the next request.

From the look of your `edit` action, there should already be some method in your controller which initializes the `@user` object before the action code gets executed. Look for `before_action` callback.

The method probably looks up the user by the email passed in the `params`. When action itself gets executes, the `@user` object is already there so it might seem Rails somehow knows how to get it. It doesn't, your controller code makes this happen.

Therefore you need hidden tag to pass context between actions. There are other ways to do that, like using `session` or `cookies`, but this way is probably the simplest.

Comment: you hit the bull's eye! I have a ``before_action`` for the ``update`` action, finding the user by the ``params[:email]``. This makes much more sense now, thanks!

Comment: @nic what you mean by saying we can use `session` or `cookies`? user hasn't log in yet, he/she has forgotten password right

Comment: Session and cookies are available regardless of whether the user is logged in or not. It is the programmer's choice what to place in either of them.